# Calculo em consulta no Banco de dados

Tags: mysql

Galera estou com um certo problema se fazer uma consulta no BD, o `SELECT` faz um calculo de algumas colunas no banco e gera um novo campo com o nome `lucro` porém se tem numero com virgula ele ignora a virgula e não mostra nesse novo campo gerado, se alguém me der uma luz de como fazer ele calcular a virgula junto agradeço

código da consulta:

```
 SELECT ID_Pacote,produto.Nome, 
 peca,FK_ID_Produto,Quantidade,Data_entrada,Data_saida 
 ,CONCAT(ROUND(pacote.Quantidade * produto.Preco  ), ' R$ ') 
 AS 'Lucro'  FROM Pacote INNER JOIN Produto on pacote.FK_ID_Produto = 
 produto.ID_Produto
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No teu SQL, o uso do ROUND está incorreto, ele está arredondando sem casa decimal.

Utilize dessa forma:

```
ROUND(pacote.Quantidade * produto.Preco, 2) -- o 2 significa 2 casas decimais :)
```

No caso seu SQL ficaria:

```
SELECT ID_Pacote,produto.Nome, 
 peca,FK_ID_Produto,Quantidade,Data_entrada,Data_saida 
 ,CONCAT(ROUND(pacote.Quantidade * produto.Preco, 2  ), ' R$ ') 
 AS 'Lucro'  FROM Pacote INNER JOIN Produto on pacote.FK_ID_Produto = 
 produto.ID_Produto
```

Mais informações de como usar, acesse esse [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_round.asp)

Espero ter ajudado! :)

Comment: Funcionou, Valeu, eu aprendi a fazer da maneira errada, obrigado pela dica

Comment: Opa, que ótimo... Não esqueça de marcar como resposta correta, pois outras pessoas podem passar pelo mesmo problema e já encontram a solução.. :)

Comment: Marco sim, só precisa esperar 5 min pra marcar sksk

Comment: cara me tira uma duvida, eu queria colocar o `R$` antes do valor, alguma sugestão ?

Comment: Usa o concat(), tipo CONCAT('R$ ', '10,00');
Dá um curte em: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp

Comment: Valeu Man :)...